# How rename namespace Application in SonataUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

My composer file:

```
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.3",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "*",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "~2.2",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~1.1",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "~0.4@dev",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "~2.2"
```

If I use "php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate -d src/ SonataUserBundle" - command generate namespace "Application", all my Bundles in namespace "WPE"...
I want user bundle in my namespace.

User entity renamed to "WPE\UserBundle\Entity\User", login, admin all work, but 
users list in sonata send error **"Class Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User does not exist"**

I find (Find in path... in IDE PhpStorm) "Application\Sonata\UserBundle" in cache files and sonata documentation.

How I can use my namespace "WPE"?

Comment: Make sure you have cleared your cache

Comment: I clear cache, first with "app/console cache:clear", when I try delete folder "app/cache/dev/"
When cache create - it have "Application\Sonata\UserBundle", but it only in cache, I don't find anything in "src" or "vendor" folders...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Rename `Application\Sonata\UserBundle` to your `YourVendor\UserBundle\Entity\User`.
2. Rename `Application\Sonata\UserBundle...` namespace to `YourVendor\UserBundle\...` in all files.
3. Remove new `Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle()` from `Appkernel.php` and add `YourVendor\UserBundle()` in `AppKernel.php`.
4. Change config:

   ```
   sonata_user:
        #security_acl: true # Uncomment for ACL support
        manager_type: orm # can be orm or mongodb
        class:
           user:               YourVendor\UserBundle\Entity\User
           group:              YourVendor\UserBundle\Entity\Group
   fos_user:
        db_driver:  orm # can be orm or odm
        firewall_name:  main
        user_class:  YourVendor\UserBundle\Entity\User
        #user_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group:
          group_class:  YourVendor\UserBundle\Entity\Group
          #group_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
          group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager
        service:
          user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
   ```
5. If your are using orm mapping:

   ```
   mappings:
        YourVendorUserBundle: ~
        #ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

**A PRAGMATIC WAY TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE**

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use global namespace inside your VB, the global namespace is the only namespace allowed `Application\YourBundle\Entity`.

So, inside your mapping definition or inside your VB code, you will use one final namespace: problem solved. How to achieve this:

Declare only SuperClass inside a VB, don’t use final entity,
Call your entity BaseXXXX and make it abstract, change the properties from private to protected,
The same goes for a repository,
Always use `Application\YourBundle\Entity\XXXX` inside your code.
Of course, you need to create for each VB bundle:

a valid structure inside the Application directory,
a valid entity mapping definition,
a model inside the entity folder.
The last part is quite inefficient without an efficient tool to generate for you this structure: EasyExtendsBundle to the rescue.

**HOW TO MAKE YOUR BUNDLE EASY EXTENDABLE?**

Mainly all you need is to follow instructions in previous paragraph:

Declare you entity/repository as described above,
Use your entity/repository as described above,
Before generation you also need “skeleton” file that will describe AB entity. Skeleton file can either xml or yml. For fully working example see SonataMediaBundle.
At last you can run:

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate YourVBBundleName
```

Note that the `–dest` option allows you to choose the target directory, such as src. Default destination is `app/`.

Comment: SonataEasyExtendsBundle create new bundle in global namespace "Application", I want in my namespace "WPE"...

Comment: If you specify no parameter, the files are generated in app/Application/Sonata... but you can specify the path with –dest=src

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use :

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate YourVBBundleName
```

You can modify some SonataAdmin fiels , it's not the best way but that can help you to run at least the commande and generate your bundle:

1 - In Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\Bundle\BundleMetadata (ligne 95) make change like this:

```
 $this->extendedNamespace = sprintf('WPE\\%s\\%s', $this->vendor, $information[1]);
```

2 - In Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\Command\GenerateCommand (ligne 67) :

```
            'application_dir' =>  sprintf("%s/WPE", $dest)
```

3 - in Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\Generator\BundleGenerator (ligne 70 ) :

```
        $file = sprintf('%s/WPE%s.php', $bundleMetadata->getExtendedDirectory(), $bundleMetadata->getName());
```

4 - In sonata-project / Resources / skeleton / bundle / bundle.mustache :

```
class WPE{{ bundle }} extends Bundle
{
 /.../
}
```

5 - In Sonata\UserBundle\DependencyInjection\SonataUserExtension (ligne 162/163):

```
 $defaultConfig['class']['user']  = sprintf('WPE\\Sonata\\UserBundle\\%s\\User', $modelType);

 $defaultConfig['class']['group'] = sprintf('WPE\\Sonata\\UserBundle\\%s\\Group', $modelType);
```

Then Run php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate.

Other way you can copy the UserBundle under WPE and make your change :

In config.yml

Your name spaces

You entities

your service

and Your class admin